# stored unreadable text - NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, json

I am new to objective C. I got a situation which causes me a lot of trouble...
In my app, there is a textField where people can enter comments and then I will store it in the server and display them somewhere else. However, some of these comments are in different languages... e.g. Chinese... and it returns some unreadable strings such as "ä½ å¥½" in the server. I am pretty sure the server is set up properly...
My question is: are there any standard ways/methods that I can get the server to recognize those foreign text?

Many thanks in advance!

The followings are my codes.

```
    NSMutableDictionary *query = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    [query setValue:userCommentTextField.text forKey:@"Comment"];

    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:query options:0 error:NULL]; // set dictionary as JSON

    NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testURL"]];

    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [req setHTTPBody:postData];

    [req setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

Comment: Unicode handles almost all languages. The problem is probably in the display code, ensure it handles unicode, not just ASCII.

Comment: FYI - please use `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`. They have specific uses and you are using the wrong one here.

Comment: Thx. Let me try setObject:forKey, but will it solve my problem?

Comment: yes, is unicode. Anything I can do in xcode?

Comment: Where are you seeing the unreadable text? On the server or on some client that gets the data from the server? How do you know the server is storing the data properly? How do you know the server is sending the data to the client properly?

Comment: I see the unreadable text in the server. The server is set up by my partner. I "guess" he did a good job. And we went thru it a few time and didn't seem to find any error. So I guess it is my problem from the xcode end...

Comment: The iOS code is going to send encoded UTF-8 versions of the comments. You need to work with the server developer to make sure that is how the data is being processed and then stored properly in UTF-8 format. Then of course you need to make sure that however you are looking at the server data is not actually the problem.

Comment: How do you "I see the unreadable text in the server."? In an html view, in a database, in a text file? Insure that the display and text format match, UTF-8 or UTF-16 (note there are different UTF-16 forms, with and without BOM and big or little endian).

Comment: Let me check with him again. Does it mean I did nothing wrong from my end, judging from the code above?

Comment: Look at what you are sending with a network analyzer such as Charles Proxy.